# How to average certain sized subsections of a list in python?

Tags: python, list, average

I would like to take bites out of a list (or array) of a certain size, return the average for that bite, and then move on to the next bite and do that all over again. Is there some way to do this without writing a for loop?

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: x = range(10)
In [3]: np.average(x[:4])
Out[3]: 1.5
In [4]: np.average(x[4:8])
Out[4]: 5.5
In [5]: np.average(x[8:])
Out[5]: 8.5
```

I'm looking for something like, np.average(x[:bitesize=4]) to return: [1.5,5.5,8.5].

I have looked at slicing arrays and stepping through arrays, but I haven't found anything that does something like I want to have happen.

Comment: Why don't you want to write a for loop?  When people ask questions trying to do something without some arbitrary control structure, it often suggests that they're in the unfortunate "do as much as possible in one line" mindset.

If it's performance you're worried about, then say that, and give an example of the size of data you're dealing with so people know what to test.

Comment: I could write a for loop, but this had the same feel to me as many other list or array manipulations that I wrote for loops for until I figured out that you could step through arrays, for example. So I asked.

Also, the for loop that I would written would have been declaring a new list, starting a for loop, running through an if statement (or two), appending values to my new list, and probably more. So the for loop one person's already answered is both clear to me and non-tragic in the programming sense that mine would have been.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[np.average(x[i:i+4]) for i in xrange(0, len(x), 4) ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `grouper` [`itertools` recipe](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes) can help.

Answer (score 1):

Using numpy, you can use `np.average` with the `axis` keyword:

```
import numpy as np
x=np.arange(12)
y=x.reshape(3,4)
print(y)
# [[ 0  1  2  3]
#  [ 4  5  6  7]
#  [ 8  9 10 11]]
print(np.average(y,axis=1))
# [ 1.5  5.5  9.5]
```

Note that to reshape `x`, I had to make `x` start with a length evenly divisible by the group size (in this case 4).

If the length of `x` is not evenly divisible by the group size, then could create a masked array and use `np.ma.average` to compute the appropriate average.

For example,

```
x=np.ma.arange(12)
y=x.reshape(3,4)
mask=(x>=10)
y.mask=mask
print(y)
# [[0 1 2 3]
#  [4 5 6 7]
#  [8 9 -- --]]
print(np.ma.average(y,axis=1))
# [1.5 5.5 8.5]
```

Comment: This actually answers a latent mask array question that I've had but haven't asked...